# How do I Crossfade music in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Simple enough... I have a background song playing on my game, and I would like to crossfade a track, instead of a hard stop.

```
//Prep Background Music
        if (![[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]isBackgroundMusicPlaying]) {
             [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadBackgroundMusic:@"song.mp3"];
        }
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setBackgroundMusicVolume:1.0]; 

        //Play Background Music
         if (![[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]isBackgroundMusicPlaying]) {
             [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"song.mp3" loop:YES];
         }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that using `SimpleAudioEngine`. Here is how I did it:

1. Create a class that extends `CDAudioManager`
2. In the method that you call to start playing a new background music, first check if the ivar `backgroundMusic` (inherited from `CDAudioManager`) is not nil and is playing. If it is, then fade it out using `CDLongAudioSourceFader`.
3. Load the new background music into `backgroundMusic` (it's an instance of `CDLongAudioSource` -- look it up). Fade it in using `CDLongAudioSourceFader`.

Here's a snippet of the method in step 2 (sorry can't show you the rest as it is part of my own proprietary library)

```
- (void)audioBackgroundPlay:(NSString *)bgmfile crossfade:(float)fade {
    CDLongAudioSource *audioSource = [self audioBackgroundLoad:bgmfile];
    if (audioSource != backgroundMusic) {
        if (backgroundMusic) {
            [self audioBackgroundControl:AUDIOCTRL_STOP fade:fade];
            backgroundMusic.audioSourcePlayer.meteringEnabled = NO;
            [backgroundMusic release];
        }
        backgroundMusic = [audioSource retain];
        if (meteringEnabled_) {
            backgroundMusic.audioSourcePlayer.meteringEnabled = YES;
        }
    }
    if (![backgroundMusic isPlaying]) {
        [self audioBackgroundControl:AUDIOCTRL_PLAY fade:fade];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this simple method to replace current background music:

```
-(void)replaceBackgroundMusic:(NSString *)filePath volume:(float)volume
{
    // no music's playing right now
    if (![[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] isBackgroundMusicPlaying])
        return [self playBackgroundMusic:filePath volume:volume];

    // already playing requested track
    if ([filePath isEqualToString:[[[CDAudioManager sharedManager] backgroundMusic] audioSourceFilePath]])
        return;

    // replace current track with fade out effect
    float currentVolume = [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].backgroundMusicVolume;
    id fadeOut = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:1 key:@"backgroundMusicVolume" from:currentVolume to:0.0f];
    id playNew =
    [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
     {
         [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setBackgroundMusicVolume:volume];
         [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:filePath];
     }];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] addAction:[CCSequence actions:fadeOut, playNew, nil] target:[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] paused:NO];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @adam.artajew's answer! I modified it to use with `Cocos2D v3` and made a category `Crossfade` on audio engine to use it from any place in the game. Now it performs following actions:

- Fade out
- Change track
- Fade in

In `OALSimpleAudio+Crossfade.m` include these imports:

```
#import "CCDirector_Private.h"
#import "CCActionManager.h"
```

And implement method:

```
- (void)playBg:(NSString *)name crossfade:(BOOL)crossfade {

    // Skip if already playing requested track
    if (self.bgPlaying &&
        [self.backgroundTrack.currentlyLoadedUrl.lastPathComponent isEqualToString:name]) {
        return;
    }

    // Play right now if no crossfade needed
    if (!crossfade) {
        [self playBg:name loop:true];
    }

    // Fade out just if music's playing right now
    NSMutableArray *actions = [NSMutableArray array];
    if (self.bgPlaying) {
        id fadeOut = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:0.5 key:@"bgVolume" from:self.bgVolume to:0.0f];
        [actions addObject:fadeOut];
    }
    // Replace current track with fade in effect
    id playNew = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        [self playBg:name loop:true];
    }];
    id fadeIn = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:0.5 key:@"bgVolume" from:0.0f to:1.0f];
    // Combime final action
    [actions addObjectsFromArray:@[playNew, fadeIn]];
    id sequence = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:actions.copy];

    // Run action
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] addAction:sequence target:self paused:NO];
}
```

**Usage:** Include `OALSimpleAudio+Crossfade.h` and call

```
[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playBg:@"MainBgMusic.mp3" crossfade:YES];
```